# Google penalty for multiple content

Tags: url-rewriting

Let's say I have one html page. By URL rewriting I manage that 100 URLs lead to that page. Would Google recognize that as multiple content and gives me a penalty? (I don't  attempt to do this, it's just a theoretical question)

Behind the scenes: 
I want to have some different URLs with the title included due to technical reasons. (I cannot use the same long URL everywhere.)
So now I'm afraid how google will react to this.

Thanks for answers!

EDIT:
Two examples, these URLs lead to the same page:

```
http://myexample.com/holidays/entry14/My-great-title
http://myexample.com/holidays/entry14
```

There are a lot of websites which do this - but as I said - I don't really know how google will react on this. A penalty is a dangerous thing.

Comment: Do you mean having a content page that just replaces keywords in the body copy based on a URL parameter?

Comment: Not sure but in that case I would use the canonical tag to specify the main page.

Comment: The question probably does not belong here.